# Lubuntu window geometry - force window to always open in the same location?

Tags: lubuntu, chromium, window, openbox

I'd like my Chromium window to open with the same size and in the same place every time. I thought I'd be able to make this happen by editing lubuntu-rc.xml like this:

chromium-browser --geometry=140x40+0+0

But it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Chromium *does* remember the last size, but never the last location.

Comment: Does chromium always open in unoccupied space?

Comment: OP may be wanting to open the browser every time in a specific position with a specific size, whether or not other applications are open? I guess what you're pointing out is that the window manager tries to display windows so that they don't overlap (or overlap minimally); is that right?

Comment: Please explain where you place this `chromium-browser --geometry=140x40+0+0` in lubuntu-rc.xml. If you wish, you may edit your question to include this information. Also, just in case you aren't aware, you need to refresh "openbox" after you edit lubuntu-rc.xml by running `openbox --reconfigure` in a terminal. If you just get back your prompt, it means your file is in good shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to get Google Chrome (and presumably Chromium) to always open with the same size and in the same screen position in a default installation of Lubuntu 12.10:

**Part 1:**
Back up `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`.
Open `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` in a text editor.
Just above the line that contains only `</keyboard>`, paste the following (modified as per requirements):

```
<keybind key="W-C">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --window-size=675,725 %U</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

**Part 2:**
Just above the line that contains only `</applications>` (near the end of the file),  paste the following (modified as per requirements):

```
<application name="google-chrome">
  <position force="yes">
    <x>-0</x>
    <y>0</y>
  </position>
</application>
```

Save the file and exit the text editor.
Open a terminal and run `openbox --reconfigure` to register the changes made to `lubuntu-rc.xml`.
Launch Google Chrome by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Notes:

- the `window-size=w,h` switch and other switches can be found here: [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).
- <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd> stand for <kbd>Control</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and <kbd>Super</kbd> (or Windows) keys, respectively.
- The combination of `<x>-0</x>` and `<y>0</y>` forces the upper right corner of the Google Chrome window to be positioned in the upper right corner of the screen.
- A combination of `<x>0</x>` and `<y>0</y>` would force the left upper corner of the Google Chrome  window to be positioned in the upper left corner of the screen.
- The comments in the *Applications* section of `lubuntu-rc.xml` have further details on window placement.